# PANDAs create ordinal ascending value column within Group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe 'df' that consists of:

```
col1 = datetime[64]
col2 = object
col3 = object
col4 = object
```

I would like to sort the dataframe by 'col1'. Then I'd like to group by 'col2'. Finally I would like to create an ordinal value (1,2,3) within that grouping by 'col2' and sorted by 'col1'. If there are 4 rows in a grouping by 'col2', then the values for the those rows would be [1,2,3,4], in this new column.

I know there is a 'rank()' in PANDAs, and I can use

```
df['newcol'] = df.groupby(['col2'])['col1'].rank()
```

But this doesn't give me the original dataframe column with ordinal values that number like [1,2,3] within the grouping only?

Comment: try `df['newcol'] = df.groupby(['col2']).transform(lambda g: g['col1'].rank())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to achieve something like this?  It is difficult to tell without sample data and desired result.

```
random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({col: [random.choice(list('abc')) for i in range(10)] for col in list('ABC')})
df['timestamp'] = pd.date_range('2016-1-1', periods=len(df))

df.sort_values('timestamp', inplace=True)
df['rank'] = \
    df.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda group: group.astype('category').cat.codes + 1)

>>> df
   A  B  C  timestamp rank
0  c  c  a 2016-01-01    2
1  c  b  c 2016-01-02    1
2  b  a  c 2016-01-03    1
3  a  c  c 2016-01-04    1
4  b  b  b 2016-01-05    2
5  b  a  a 2016-01-06    1
6  c  c  b 2016-01-07    2
7  a  c  b 2016-01-08    1
8  b  c  c 2016-01-09    3
9  b  c  c 2016-01-10    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
>> df.sort_values(by='col1').groupby('col2')
```

This will first sort your DF by `col1` and then group by `col2`. The result will be a GroupBy object.

If you also want to have the number of rows in each one of the groups, then you can try this:

```
>> grouped = df.sort_values(by='col1').groupby('col2')
>> grouped.count()
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There's a pandas `groupby` method that does exactly what (I think) the OP wants:

```
df.sort_values("col1", inplace = True)
df["rank"] = df.groupby("col2").cumcount() + 1
```

It might be more useful, though, to use a `MultiIndex` here:

```
df.set_index(["col1", "col2"], inplace = True)
df["rank"] = df.groupby(level = "col2").cumcount() + 1
```

To make things prettier (with the rows sorted by "col2" as well as "col1"):

```
df.sort_values(by=["col2", "col1"], inplace = True)
```